Inquiry Regarding LinkedIn API Integration
I'm currently working on integrating LinkedIn's Profile API into my application. To initiate this integration, I successfully requested access to "Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect" through the LinkedIn Developer platform. Subsequently, I was able to authenticate users and obtain user information using the userInfo endpoint.
However, I encountered an issue when attempting to access the Profile API. Despite obtaining authentication and successfully accessing user information, I'm unable to obtain permission to access the Profile API endpoints.
Could anyone provide guidance on how to resolve this issue? Are there additional steps or permissions required to access the Profile API after successful authentication with OpenID Connect?

Hi Anh Nguyen... I have been trying to integrate the linkedIn APIs in my system. can you help me with the Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect codebase like How u did it ? ... I am using nestjs.

Hi @DanishSharma, I created an app on LinkedIn Developer, requested "Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect", followed the documentation at "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?tabs=HTTPS1". During setup, I found "Step 3: Exchange Authorization Code for an Access Token" needed backend integration due to CORS restrictions. After a successful request to "POST https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken", obtained access token.
